# Is there a statement that says "if this button has been pushed (not necessarily when it has been pushed, execute.."?

Tags: swift

I'm not sure if I could do this with a *do-while* statement or what; I have a color-changing game that I am working on and I need a statement that will basically say:

> *If a button (one of the color buttons) HAS BEEN pushed (as in in the immediate past), then when the user goes to play the game by touching one of the other buttons, supply in this image. If not, continue to supply in this image.*

I am a beginner so please explain all suggestions thoroughly. Thank you!

Comment: translate your sentences to pseudo code first then translate it real code

Answer (score 1):

You could have a variable that is turned to *True* when the button is pressed and *False* when the other button is pressed. You could set the image to play only when the variable is *True*.

So if Button x sets the first image and Button y starts the game/other image it could be something like this:

```
Button x == Pressed:
  xpressed = True

if xpressed == True:
  DisplayImageHere

Button y == Pressed:
  ypressed = True
  xpressed = False

if ypressed == True:
  DisplayImageHere/Start Game
```

If you run something similar in a loop it could work.